# need some tips on how to skipp over integers in a data file all the way to the next string so i can output it

Tags: c++

I need the strings from the data file to print on the screen and in a data file as well. I got the firstoneworking, but now i cant figure out how to get the other names to work.

I need to skip the numbers after i read in the string to read in the next string in the data file.

**Here is what the data file looks like:**
John W. Smith
12.55
3
5
Mary Anderson
11.75
1
8
Brad W. Baker
11.75
0
0
Heather Johnson
13.25
2
10

**Here is my code so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const double pay1 = 12.55;
const double pay2 = 11.75;
const double pay3 = 11.75;
const double pay4 = 13.25;

int main()
{
ifstream indata;
string fname, lname, fname2, lname2;
int hours;
hours = 0;
ofstream outdata;
outdata.open("Weeklypay.dat");

cout << "Please enter the total hours worked for John W. Smith: " << endl;
cin >> hours;

double gross;
gross = pay1 * hours;
double taxes;
taxes = 0.23 * gross;
double ssecurity;
ssecurity = 0.08 * gross;
int dependants;
dependants = 3 * 12;
double retirement;
retirement = 0.05 * gross;
double net;
net = gross - taxes - ssecurity - dependants - retirement;

indata.open("Pay.dat");
getline(indata, fname);

cout << fname << lname << " 's net pay is: $" << net << endl;

outdata << fname << lname << endl;
outdata << "Gross Pay: $" << gross << endl;
outdata << "Taxes: $" << taxes << endl;
outdata << "Social Security: $" << ssecurity << endl;
outdata << "Insurance: $" << right << dependants << endl;
outdata << "Retirement: $" << retirement << endl;
outdata << endl << endl;
outdata << "Net Pay: $" << net << endl;
outdata << endl << endl;


cout << "Please enter the total hours worked for Mary Anderson: " << endl;
cin >> hours;

double gross2;
gross2 = pay2 * hours;
double taxes2;
taxes2 = 0.23 * gross;
double ssecurity2;
ssecurity2 = 0.08 * gross;
int dependants2;
dependants2 = 1 * 12;
double retirement2;
retirement2 = 0.08 * gross;
double net2;
net2 = gross - taxes - ssecurity - dependants - retirement;

indata.open("Pay.dat");
getline(indata, fname2);

cout << fname2 << lname2 << " 's net pay is: $" << net2 << endl;

outdata << fname2 << lname2 << endl;
outdata << "Gross Pay: $" << gross2 << endl;
outdata << "Taxes: $" << taxes2 << endl;
outdata << "Social Security: $" << ssecurity2 << endl;
outdata << "Insurance: $" << dependants2 << endl;
outdata << "Retirement: $" << retirement2 << endl;
outdata << endl << endl;
outdata << "Net Pay: $" << net << endl;

indata.close();
outdata.close();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data will always be in the format of `int int double fname lname`, just read in the data and do not store it:

```
int junk1;
int junk2;
double junk3;
std::string fname;
std::string lname;

std::ifstream fin("my_input_file.txt");
std::ofstream fout("my_output_file.txt");

while (fin >> junk1 >> junk2 >> junk3 >> fname >> lname)
{
    // do somethign with fname and lname
    fout << fname << lname << std::endl;
}
```

Also note that instead of declaring `fname2` and `lname2`, etc., you should use a container (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::deque`, etc). to store a collection of data.

Comment: I have to do it without using vectors or arrays ect... I just need to go into the data file and pull out the first and last names of each person and output it into a new file.

Comment: @user3312523 Easy enough - what I show here will get you the read portion, you just need to add an `std::ofstream` that will output `fname` and `lname` to the output file in the while loop.